# gstreamer create virtual device on OSX

Tags: macos, gstreamer, syphon

I would like to create a virtual camera device using gstreamer on OSX

I am able to create it on *nix systems using

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

On osx I get a erroneous pipeline `v4l2`

I would like to be able to pipe the output into applications such as skype etc.,

Any pointers in this direction ? Should I use syphon?

Comment: `v4l2` is a Linux kernel module, which you can't exactly install on macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go is to use [CoreMediaIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html) framework. You can create a virtual device using the framework and feed in any stream using a wrapper. Some pointers for wrappers can be seen [here](https://github.com/bangnoise/cmiotest).

Comment: @RoyShilkrot I posted the question and I did post the answer to my question. The answer has 2 code sample projects listed which solve the problem if you had taken the time to look. The sample project from CoreMediaIO creates a new virtual camera device and that device can be fed input. The second project shows an example how to feed an input into the created virtual device.

Answer (score 2):

This gstreamer command:

```
./gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! osxvideosink
```

Works on OSX Sierra  if you install Gstreamer on OSX from the following packages
which will install in the /Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/ folder. Execute commands from the Commands subfolder.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.12.0/

This link has a standard package, a development package and a dmg with lots of smaller distribution packages. 
To pipe output you will need to choose an appropriate sink - either appsink, and write it yourself, or one of the many other sink types in Gstreamer. 
Hope that gets you started!

Comment: I can see the video on a window using this. However, I would like to pump the video into other applications such as skype. I would like to do something like camtwist

Comment: Well on Gstreamer, the method is appsink, per the examples. Or a standard sink element ( see docs), or copy one of the elements and push the buffers yourself into your app if you want to add effects. Gstreamer requires some serious reading to get into it I am afraid.

Comment: Yup I figured out the route.

Comment: @PavanK I know this thread is very old, but could you explain what route you took?